# UITableView + Core Animation

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, core-animation

I would like to build up a **table view section** into my iOS app just like the **Facebook** style (with many information in every row, images and buttons, ..).

I also want to include **Core Animation effects** on every row, like fade out the cell, or customize the graphic interface.

Do you recommend me to use the UITableView class or something else more 'customizable'?

Comment: This is a broad question. Could you be more specific about what is what you are trying to accomplish with your specific application and animations? How customized are your cells going to be and what kind of data are you presenting? Usually core animation is a tool to get to a goal. You shouldn't make it a goal to release an app just using core animation (unless, of course, you are just trying to learn the framework).

Comment: Lets do an example:

I have n rows, each one has a picture, a title and a short description, just like the TableViewCell layout. My problem comes when I want to apply a specific effect to that row when I have to delete, add, change that row. Has the UIView/UITableView class some animations to use, or its better to ask help from Core Animation framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the regular `UITableView`, but custom `UITableViewCells`.
`UITableView`'s support fading and other kind of animations for adding/removing/reloading cells

```
NSMutableArray *affectedRows = [NSMutableArray array];
[affectedRows addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
[affectedRows addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]];

// use whatever corresponds
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:affectedRows withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];

[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:affectedRows withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];

[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:affectedRows withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
```

Be careful when using these methods, because the numberOfRowsInSection: function gets called again, and if the new result doesn't match the new number of rows, your app will crash

IE: you have 5 rows, and delete 2, your method must then return 3

Comment: Thank you! Nice question. In the case I want more effects, or a specific animation, it is possible to apply the Core Animation methods to the UITableViewCell?

Comment: I think that will be a little more complicated, since UITableView is very attached with UITableViewCell's and a small change can become a problem real quick ... if you intend on doing custom animations, you'll have to create your own TableView-Like class and do everything by hand