# UITableViewCell bend animations while scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uitableview

I need to create a table view animation like the image below while scrolling , But I have very little idea on animations. And also I need to make the selected cell to animate by going inwards and disappear while the cell above and below closes( like the animations done while deleting a Text message in iPhone).
[image: TableCell]

Comment: Hey! I'd like to give you some links, which are worth taking a look at: http://www.thinkandbuild.it/animating-uitableview-cells/, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202221/uitableview-core-animation

Comment: Great stuff! I recreated the same example from that website ,now how will I change this math    `rotation = CATransform3DMakeRotation( (90.0*M_PI)/180, 0.0, 0.7, 0.4);
    rotation.m34 = 1.0/ -600;
    cell.layer.transform = rotation;
    cell.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5)`to bring my animation

Comment: Hey! What you want to research is named Core Graphics affineTransformation. I recommend having a look here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_affine/dq_affine.html

Answer (score 3):

You have to hijack the scrollView (Add yourself as a ScrollViewDelegate alongside TableViewDelegate) and the table view will automatically forward scrollview events along side tableview events.

(self.tableView.delegate = self) is really talking to both

```
<UIScrollViewDelegate, UITableViewDelegate>
```

I have a helper function in the example that also calculates distance to the top of the cell.

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    NSArray *rows = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
    for (NSIndexPath *path in rows) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
        float percent = [self cellDistanceAsPercentageFromTableViewCenterAtRow:cell];
        cell.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeScale(percent, percent, 1);
    }
}
//Calculate distance of the cell as a percentage from the bottom of the actual visible contentView
-(float)cellDistanceAsPercentageFromTableViewCenterAtRow:(UITableViewCell *)cell {
    float position = cell.frame.origin.y;

    float offsetFromTop = self.tableView.contentOffset.y;

    float percentFromBottom = (position-offsetFromTop+ROW_HEIGHT)/self.tableView.frame.size.height;
    percentFromBottom = MIN(MAX(percentFromBottom, 0), 1);

    return percentFromBottom;
}
```